# LED indicator for DC voltage

Tags: led, voltage, power, diodes, converter

I am planning to using a buck / boost converter to run a DSLR camera from my USB powerbank AND other power sources.
For that module I want to build with the buck / boost converter, I need a simple LED voltage indicator circuit, since I need to adjust the potentiometer from the converter whenever I change the source of power.

**Example 1**

```
input: 5V from regular USB powerbank
output: 8.4V to the camera coupler
```

**Example 2**

```
input: 9V from DIY battery pack
output: 12V to other application
```

What I want the circuit to do is, when I turn the potentiometer, I want a LED to light up when the output voltage is between 8.4V and 8.6V ( ready for camera ). And when it's in an other range, I want an other LED to light up.

I've heard something about a combination of resistors and z-diodes to do the trick ?

Additionally it would be perfect, if the indicator circuit is not depending on whether the output circuit is closed or not ( camera is pluged in or not ).

Simple sketch:

[image]

Pleas tell me your ideas and solutions.

**EDIT**

I've found this [link](http://www.eleccircuit.com/simple-voltage-indicator-by-led-and-zener-diode/) that shows this circuit
[image]

How does that work and how do I calculate the values for the parts ? I didn't understand the text on the linked page.

Comment: Your output voltage is the same in both cases. Why do you need to adjust anything?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the output voltage will change depending on the input voltage, if i don't change the potentiometer. Doesn't it ?

Comment: The whole point of a voltage regulator is that it produces the same output voltage regardless of load current and input voltage, within its limitations. You don't say what you're using, but it's unlikely that it needs adjusting. And, if it does, you should get a better regulator.

Comment: okay thank you, I will check that as soon as I can. But it would be nice anyway to be able to check if the voltage is in the range I want, since I don't want to overpower my camera... also maybe I want to use the regulator for other applications, where I need other output voltages, since I'm building it modular. Therefore it would be nice to know a circuit that lets me light up a LED for each range I choose.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious solution of buying a cheap LED panel voltmeter off EBay and hooking that up?

Comment: yes I could, but I want a minimalistic and power saving solution. The LED'S will only be light up when a pushbutton is pressed down while regulating. Since this is a process that will be done once in a while, I don't want to invest too much in that feature.

Comment: @Ace: You could supply the LED voltmeter from a pushbutton. If you really want to build it yourself the term to search for is "voltage comparator" or "window comparator". As long as you don't have any spare opamps lying around and time/curiosity to fiddle with your circuit I would use an off the shelf solution (I found one for 1€ including shipping).

Comment: Voltage "bargraph" ICs may work well for this; they provide 10 led outputs but you only need to connect two.

Comment: I've updated my question and the examples for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

As ox6d64, motioned, you can use a window comparator.  The trick is, what to compare to, since you have varying supply voltages.

Here I am using a [LT1461](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1461fa.pdf) voltage reference that can handle input voltages up to 20V and  puts out 3.3V with 0.04% accuracy.  So it is like a very precise voltage regulator but lower current (50 mA).  That is still enough to drive a some LEDs besides serving as a reference.

[image]

It then uses two comparators.  The input voltage is fed into two voltage dividers; the top one yields 3.29 volts when fed an input of 8.6V:

$$\frac{6.04kΩ}{9.76kΩ + 6.04kΩ} \times 8.6V = 3.29V$$

and the bottom one yields 3.31V when fed an input of 8.4V:

$$\frac{6.49kΩ}{10kΩ + 6.49kΩ} \times 8.4V = 3.31V$$

I couldn't get exactly 3.3V with either divider since the exact resistor values weren't available.  The standard 1% resistor values [are here](http://www.brannonelectronics.com/images/STANDARD%20VALUE.pdf).

So the bottom comparator will output a high when the voltage is above 8.4V, and the top comparator will output a high when the voltage is below 8.6V.  These two conditions are ANDed together using the NAND gate.  I use the latter so when it is asserted, it outputs a ground and turns on the LED.

You can modify the circuit to work with whatever other voltages you need to measure.

Comment: And putting the (open-collector) comparators the right way around will allow you to wire-OR them, saving the logic gate.

Comment: Also note that the comparitor outputs need pull-up resistors or the circuit (as shown) won't work.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Noted (and good suggestion), however I left the circuit as since it is easier to understand with an explicit AND gate.